# Is operating point calculation the same for P-JFET and N-JFET with voltage-divider bias?

Tags: jfet

I've seen this calculation of operating point for N-JFET:

[image]
<sub>(source: [prenhall.com](https://wps.prenhall.com/wps/media/objects/416/426156/fig129.gif))</sub>

Together with the relation \$I_D = I_{DSS}(1-V_{GS}/U_P)^2\$, it is possible to find \$I_D\$ and \$V_{SD}\$.

This method doesn't take into account that it's a N-JFET. Does this mean that the result would be identical for a P-JFET? (I think it is, because we assume that there is no current through the gate, so P/N-ness wouldn't matter.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon so: -

[image]

Taken from [here](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/mleach/ece3050/notes/jfet/thejfet.pdf)