# How do the hybrid-pi models between N-channel and P-channel JFETs differ?

Tags: transistors, polarity

This is the hybrid-pi model of an n-channel JFET.

[image]

[An answer on here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/86323/is-operating-point-calculation-the-same-for-p-jfet-and-n-jfet-with-voltage-divid) claimed that the only difference between p-channel and n-channel JFETs is that voltages are reversed. How would this apply to the hybrid-pi model?

I would guess that the model would be identical to the one above except for changing the sign on \$v_{gs}\$, so that the source is positive, gate is negative, and current flows from source to drain. But I don't have sufficient understanding to know if this is correct. Is it?

If so, what about the h-parameter model for bipolar transistors? What would differ between N-channel and P-channel?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim for that answer is true. You should remember that the hybrid-pi, T or h models are small signal equivalent models where the small signal parameters are derivatives of the large signal model at a specific operating point. Since the derivative is a linear operator, the small signal model will encounter the same effect, of reversing the subscripts, or just negating the voltages.

You could simply modify the hybrid-pi model of the N-channel JFET as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxmed4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You should note that this circuit would have been the exact equivalent to the model you provided if I swap \$ v_{sg} \$ with \$ -v_{gs} \$.